Free body diagram problem: Linkage w/ magnets and friction hinge
I am a bit stumped on a IRL problem, which i simplified in the diagram below:
There are left and right beams (gray) linked together by a friction hinge. The bottom beam (black) is connected to the left and right beam by a frictionless pivot point (on the right), and another frictionless pivot point w/ a slider (on the left). There are magnets (green) embedded on the left and right beams that are attracting the magnets embedded on the bottom beam.
Given the following variables:
distances/lengths: A,H,B and C
torque of the friction hinge: T_friciton_hinge
attraction force of magnet: F_magnet1 and F_magnet2
Assume perfectly rigid beams.
Solve the maximum downward force (F_load) possible before the friction hinge rotates

Here what I tried to do to solve for F_load:

Let me know if my thought process is unreasonable.

Some questions.
-Is the black beam flexible? If not, why include it on the diagram?
-The slider at the left end should give a vertical reaction (if not, it would not be a slider, just a free end), which makes $F_{load}$ redundant.
-Is the hinge a "static friction" kind of thing? i.e. no rotation until a threshold moment is surpassed?

Hi @Zegpi, assume black beam is rigid. If you apply an excessive F_load, this would happen: https://imgur.com/a/tY9OyqH, where the friction hinge would rotate, and the magnets would separate. Hope this makes sense.
Yep, assume static friction for the hinge.

Got it about the hinge and the black bar, but what about the slider?
As presented, F_load has no effect on the gray beam, as it will go directly to the black bar. As it's presented, your system looks like it simplifies to this diagram https://imgur.com/a/R5bKAmc .
